# SQL Allow exactly one specific value on attribute of a table ON CREATION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if there is a way in sql to allow a column to have any value it wants for its attributes, but only one of them can be X value.

More specifically for easier explanations let's say i have:

> create table status(  current_status varchar(100),  id integer )

what constraint should i add so i can only have up to one value of current_status='ACCEPTED' ?

EDIT:REMOVED mysql TAG

Comment: You need a trigger for that, as long as you can't use a UNIQUE constraint to achieve this.

Comment: `create unique index ui on status(current_status);`

Comment: @VaoTsun No, because he had asked to "allow a column to have any value it wants for its attributes, but only one of them can be X value". A UNIQUE constraint would only allow one value of any type.

Comment: For PostgreSQL: A [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) can do that. You could index literally any expression with `WHERE (current_status = 'ACCEPTED')` -- I'm not sure why do you tagged multiple vendors though.

Comment: Postgresql and MySQL are two different products with different features. Which one do you use? Or if you use both, then do you need a single solution that works across both?

Comment: oh wow, my bad. no idea how mysql tag slipped from me.

Comment: Thanks everyone it seems correct for pgSql

Answer (score 1):

[Partial index in Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html)

```
create unique index index_accepted on status (current_status)
where current_status = 'ACCEPTED'
```

Comment: This is applicable to postgresql only and does not work in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you and i apologise once more that i had 2 tags for that.
my current question was for pgSQL so it solved my problem